# Don't Save to File if file exists NSFileManager

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

I have a NSFileManager that searches for a file and if the file doesn't exist it creates one and if it does exist it writes to it. But what I want it to be is that if the file exist it doesn't write to it. Here is my code.

```
NSString *docPath =[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%@", docPath);
NSString *results=[docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"results.csv"];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:results]) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
     createFileAtPath:results contents:nil attributes:nil];
}
NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:results];
[fileHandle seekToEndOfFile];
[fileHandle writeData:[save dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[fileHandle closeFile];
NSLog(@"info saved");
```

How would I be able to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You should accept Flexicoder's answer, but obviously, if `save` is a `NSString` you can simplify this a bit:

```
NSString *docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *results = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"results.csv"];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:results])
    [save writeToFile:results atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Comment: Not thread-safe; there is a potential race condition where the file does not exist when fileExistsAtPath: is called, but by the time writeToFile: is called the file does exist, and gets overwritten. I'm looking for a thread-safe solution to this problem; it is perplexing that the Cocoa APIs seem to provide no way to do this easily.

Comment: @bhaller - Convert to `NSData` and then use [`writetofile:options:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1414800-writetofile?language=objc) with the “[no overwrite](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdatawritingoptions/nsdatawritingwithoutoverwriting?language=objc)” option.

Comment: Yep, I discovered that eventually – although the doc does not actually guarantee that the operation is atomic, as far as I can tell.  Maybe that option just calls `fileExistsAtPath:` for you, and has the same issue.

Comment: It’s not atomic. And I’m confident it doesn’t just call `fileExists`. This is a well understood problem and that’s the whole purpose of that option. The other approach is to write to a temp file and [move it](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager/1413529-moveitematpath?language=objc) when it’s done. Or consider https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager/1412432-replaceitematurl?language=objc

Comment: Wait, you say it's *not* atomic, but you also say that resolving this race condition is "the whole purpose of that option"?  How can it be both?  Either it resolves the issue, by being atomic, or it doesn't... no?

Comment: No. It doesn’t solve the race issue by being atomic (because as the docs say, it can’t be combined with atomic). Besides, atomic file operations are solving a completely different problem, namely file integrity (by creating temp file & moving to destination later). The “don’t overwrite” option solves the race by combining the existence-check and the file-write into one step (e.g. EAFP rather than LBYL).

Comment: Ah – that is what I mean by "atomic".  From the Greek "atom", meaning "cannot be cut"; the existence-check and the file-write cannot be cut in two by a filesystem operation coming from some other thread/app.  But yes, the Cocoa doc use "atomic" to mean something a bit different, so that is confusing.  :->  Thanks for the clarification.  But does using "NSDataWritingWithoutOverwriting" actually guarantee that the operation is "atomic" in my sense of the word?  The doc just says it is a "hint", which does not inspire confidence.

Answer (score 1):

Enclose all your code within the if statement

```
NSString *docPath =[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%@", docPath);
NSString *results=[docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"results.csv"];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:results]) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
 createFileAtPath:results contents:nil attributes:nil];
    NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:results];
    [fileHandle seekToEndOfFile];
    [fileHandle writeData:[save dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [fileHandle closeFile];
    NSLog(@"info saved");
}
```

Comment: Not thread-safe; there is a potential race condition where the file does not exist when fileExistsAtPath: is called, but by the time createFileAtPath: is called the file does exist, and gets overwritten.  I'm looking for a thread-safe solution to this problem; it is perplexing that the NSFileManager APIs seem to provide no way to do this easily.